# Help with understanding Data Designer and attribute groups for checking promo code usage

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, data-designer

I need some help wrapping my head around this. I figure the best way is an actual use case I have.

I have multiple journeys running. Each journey has a decision split that is checking to see if a specific promo code has been used. The promo code is a general code (like HELLO123) that can be used once only be each customer.

My current understanding of the way the decision splits work is this:

I have a DE (as below) that is linked via data designer

```
-----------------------------
| SubscriberKey | Promocode |
-----------------------------
| 1234          | ABCD      |
| 1234          | ZXYW      |
| 1234          | POUY      |
| 9876          | ABCD      |
-----------------------------
```

If I used a decision split to check if SubscriberKey 1234 had used Promocode POUY, it would return FALSE as it would start at the top of the list, run down until it first found SubscriberKey 1234, and then return the Promocode value (ABCD)

Am I understanding that behaviour correctly?

---

In order to do this properly, I think I need to create more relationships between data extensions. Eg:

- Customer DE, where SubscriberKey is the primary key
- Promocode DE (as above)
- Link them where SubscriberKey = SubscriberKey in a 1-many cardinality

If I have this setup, how would the decision split then behave? Would it actually check for all instances of the SubscriberKey in the Promocode DE and therefore be able to check for the presence of any promocode?

Thanks